# @joinedcolumn not correctly mapped by hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, joincolumn

I'm facing an issue when running unit test with hibernate trying to make some tests against my repository (spring boot+jpa application). below the config i'm using
It consists of 3 entities Record, Order an Status:

```
@Table(name = "T_RECORD")
public class Record implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    private Long cardId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Order order;
}

@Table(name = "T_ORDER")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID")
    private String externalOrderId;

    @Column(name = "INPUT_FILE_NAME")
    private String inputFileName;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    private Integer quantity;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "STATUS_CODE",
            referencedColumnName = "CODE",
            nullable = false
    )
    private Status statusCode;
}

@Table(name = "T_STATUS")
public class Status implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
  private Integer code;
}
```

my unit test against record repository is the following:

```
private static final Status STATUS = Status.builder()
            .id(ID_STATUS)
            .name(STATUS_NAME)
            .code(STATUS_CODE)
            .build();

    private static final Order ORDER = Order.builder()
            .id(ID_ORDER)
            .customerId(CUSTOMER_ID)
            .externalOrderId(EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID)
            .inputFileName(INPUT_FILE_NAME)
            .quantity(QUANTITY)
            .statusCode(STATUS)
            .build();

    private static final Record RECORD = Record.builder()
            .id(ID_RECORD)
            .customerId(CUSTOMER_ID)
            .cardId(CARD_ID)
            .order(ORDER)            
            .build();

    @Test
    public void findByCustomerIdAndCardId() {

        statusRepository.save(STATUS);
        orderRepository.save(ORDER);
        recordRepository.save(RECORD);

        List<Record> newRecords = recordRepository.findByCustomerIdAndCardId(CUSTOMER_ID, CARD_ID);
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(newRecords.get(0), Matchers.is(Matchers.equalTo(RECORD)));
    }
```

When running the test, i'm getting the following error:

> Hibernate: insert into T_ORDER (CUSTOMER_ID,
> CUSTOMER_ORDER_ID, EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID,
> INPUT_FILE_NAME, INPUTFILE_DATE,
> QUANTITY, STATUS_CODE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2021-12-02 11:09:03.316 WARN 16512
> --- [ main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502 2021-12-02 11:09:03.316 ERROR 16512 --- [ main]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : NULL not allowed for column
> "STATUS_CODE"; SQL statement: insert into T_ORDER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_ORDER_ID, EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID, INPUT_FILE_NAME, INPUTFILE_DATE,
> QUANTITY, TATUS_CODE, ID)
> values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-200]

Hibernate is using NULL for the value of the status code (which is not a primary key) intead of Status.code
Please i'm not sure about the annotations used between the entities, so i don't know what i'm doing wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Could it be that your repositories are simply not mutating your objects (setting their ids)? You might have to update the variables after saving them, like this: `status = statusRepository.save(status)` (you have to remove `final` for that). Also if you do that, check if the `Status` object is a new instance, if thats the case then you have to set it in your `Order` object again

Comment: nope. unfortunately it still not working by removing final for all entities, and setting the status into order as following: 
        `Status status = statusRepository.save(STATUS);
        ORDER.setStatus(status);
        Order order = orderRepository.save(ORDER);
        RECORD.setOrder(order);
        recordRepository.save(RECORD);`

Comment: did you copy paste the error you posted or did you alter that in any way? in the last line it says `TATUS_CODE` .